# R - zip file extract

Tags: r, unzip

It's very silly not to find the solution here, so I write the question.I'm sorry upfront if its too basic.

I have a zip file in directory

`dir <- "C:/Users/...`

`setwd(dir`

`to_open <- list.files(dir,".zip")`

> to_open
>
> [1] "getdata-projectfiles-UCI HAR Dataset.zip"

And now I tried some 100 functions just to see the zipped directory. There are some 3 files with some 5 csv/txt files each.

How can I call them from inside R?

So far I only succeeded with `unzip(to_open)` which leaves a mess behind with more files in the directory and less reproducible code.

Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could `unzip` the files one by one into another directory and clean up afterward

```
td <- tempdir()
unzip(file_to_unzip, ex = td)
# do something with the files
file.remove(list.files(td, full.names = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks. I could open, but when removing, I get this error:

> file.remove(list.files(td, fullnames = TRUE))
Error in list.files(td, fullnames = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (fullnames = TRUE)

Comment: that should be `full.names`